# Set height in different object

Tags: transforms

I have two objects (Avatar and base) separated with random dimensions. I need to scale them using a specific dimension (in this case, the avatar's height). I want to scale the avatar in 1.60 height and the base proportionally. How Can I do it?

[image]

Comment: what if you select both the 2 objects, switch to Edit mode, select all, press SZ1.6?

Comment: It doesn't work. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot, maybe even share your file so that we understand?

Comment: The file is too heavy, I can share the screenshot